# Unable to deploy Intellij project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I basically am running a Java web app on Intellij and it works fine when I tried to deploy and run it.

As I pull my colleague's code from the source control to get the latest changes, I couldn't launch my project and it throws this error:

```
 Artifact Application:ear exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [Application-9.7.0] : Servlet [RegistrationCoordinatorPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.jws.WebService(wsdlLocation=/wsdls/wsc10/wscoor.wsdl, targetNamespace=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wscoor, name=, endpointInterface=com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.types.RegistrationRequesterPortType, portName=RegistrationRequesterPortTypePort, serviceName=RegistrationService_V10)] on annotated element [class com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.endpoint.RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] of type [TYPE]. Please see server.log for more details.
```

In the Glassfish log, it says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet [RegistrationCoordinatorPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebBundleDescriptorImpl.addWebComponentDescriptor(WebBundleDescriptorImpl.java:362)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.connector.annotation.handlers.WebServiceHandler.processAnnotation(WebServiceHandler.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.factory.SJSASFactory$LazyAnnotationHandler.processAnnotation(SJSASFactory.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:350)
    ... 60 more
]]
```

I've looked around this thread for other people with similar issue and it doesn't work for my case. More importantly, why does this even happen?

What is the cause of this problem and how do I go about to fix it or what to look at?

Comment: Please press Ctrl-Shift-F, type in  `RegistrationService_V10` and press enter. What do you see, where is this string in the code ?

Comment: @krokodilko I thought of that before, unfortunately, it's unable to show  no results so it makes it harder for me to resolve this issue

Comment: Checkout the latest your working revision from repossitory and then compare current revision of your coleges with that working one, mayby this give you some hint?

Comment: I did that as well but it's identical apart from some of her working changes but this error has to do with some settings rather than code wise

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace it looks like you have two servlets with the same path:

"/RegistrationService_V10"

Such error can only show up during runtime. Normally, your path should be distinct through out your project.

Comment: I tried `ctrl shift f` and look for it and nothing shows.